# Dynamic Linq custom type conversion for query

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I'm trying to use dynamic Linq (`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`) to query
data from MongoDB, based on a SQL-like string query I get from Excel.
This
works, but I'm trying to change the semantics of date - long
comparisons.

I'm trying to enable queries where I compare an ISODate field with a
double representing the Excel datetime (OLE automation date, number of
days since 1899-12-30), but any parsed long gets cast into a DateTime
based on the number of 100ns intervals since `0001-01-01T00:00.000`
Gregorian via [this overload of the datetime
constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-ctor(system-int64)).

I want to somehow change this, so that an integer/double in a
comparison gets
cast into a `DateTime` for comparison via the
`DateTime.FromOADate(Double)`
[function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=net-7.0).

The official MongoDB driver supports the `IQueryable` interface, and
I'm using
it directly.

Here's the base for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```cs
MongoClientSettings settings =
MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(
 "mongodb://my-mongo.local"
);
settings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V2;
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);

var database = client.GetDatabase("my_db");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("colls.my_coll");

/* colls.my_colls consists of members like this:
{
 "_id" : ObjectID,
 "name": string,
 "numeric": double,
 "date": ISODate
}
*/

// in the query, 44920 is the OLE automation date representation of
2022-12-25
var results = collection
 .AsQueryable<BsonDocument>()
 .AsQueryable()
 .Where("date < 44920 and name != \"badname\" and numeric >= 520");
```

This doesn't work because the integer gets interpreted in the 'wrong'
way.

One potential solution that came to my mind was to
[map](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.15/reference/bson/mapping/)
the MongoDB result to a custom class, and use a custom (DateTime-
wrapping)
class for the `date` field in it, which has the proper conversion
constructor
for int/double. I would then have to use a custom `TypeConvertor` to
implement
an automatic conversion (I found
[this](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/09657b9c097f03c9e426a1554719402e80ba9221/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/TypeConvertors/NodaTimeConverterTests.cs)
in the tests), but I don't fully understand how `TypeConvertor`s work
(I'm a
recent C++ to C# convert).

Am I on the right track? Am I missing something? Is there a better way?

Comment: How do you know that your number "gets cast into a DateTime based on the number of 100ns intervals since 0001-01-01T00:00.000"?

Comment: Experimentally + that's what the (long) overload of the constructor for DateTime does (as I've noted in the link in the OP).

Comment: Asking because if you run this dynamic linq query _without_ mongo (so, against in-memory collection) then it will fail with error about operator < cannot be applied to `DateTime` and `Int32`. So it seems to me that dynamic linq doesn't do any conversion as you describe, and that is mongodb provider doing that.